# Deletion costs on GCP cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am planning to delete numerous old small objects in GCP to save on storage costs. There is an object lifecycle policy set to delete these objects after a few years. But, we no longer require them. We wish to filter and delete them off earlier than the policy.

As per [google cloud storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class)

- *storage.buckets.delete* and *storage.objects.delete* are free operations
- However, *storage.buckets.list* and *storage.objects.list* are class-A operations costing $0.05 and $0.5 per 10k operations for standard and archived storage respectively

Query:

- Are list operations billed per API call, or by the number of objects in the result set?

I am wary of running a long operation to get a listing of all the objects in the bucket by their creation date just to find that listing operation itself costing more than the continued storage till as set in lifecycle policy. Specifically, for archive storage, listing operation is 10 times costly than that on standard storage.

Comment: Per API call for **Are list operations billed per API call, or by the number of objects in the result set?** However, be careful with your API calls so that you are not calling the same API over and over to get the same results. I have seen poorly written software that does a list and delete one object in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Listing the objects recursively is always a costly operation when you have  tens of thousands of objects. Consider adding additional lifecycle rules which would delete the objects as sooner as you require. For example, 10 days after the object has been created.

The following document lists all the available lifecycle conditions you can use to delete the objects: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#conditions